# Inotify wrongly detects event

Tags: c, linux, events, inotify

I just started using inotify, just to see how it works and I ran into a strange behaviour. So I am monitoring a file and I want to be notified about its opening and closing.

```
while(1)
{
    i = 0;
    length = read(fd[wid], buffer, BUF_LEN);
    while (i < length)
    {
        struct inotify_event* event = (struct inotify_event*) &buffer[i];
        if (event->mask & IN_OPEN)
            printf("File opened!\n");
        else if (event->mask & IN_CLOSE)
            printf("File closed!\n");
        i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
    }
}
```

This is the part of code that doesn't do what I expect it to do. So, the first thing I noticed is that if I run my program and I go to the folder where I have my file, when I open the folder it detects both opening and closing events on the file. Why is that? And how can I fix it?

The other thing is that when I open the actual file it first detects an opening event (as it should), but then it detects a closing event too, even though my file is still opened. Again, why is that happening? And what's the solution to this? And when I close the file it doesn't detects anything (this I think it's because it already wrongly detected a closing event so it sees the file as closed).

Oh, and one more thing! If I open the file (and I keep it open) with LibreOffice Writer it detects many opening/closing events. Then it waits a bit, then again it detects many opening/closing events.

Comment: The probable reason is that LibreOffice repeatedly opens and closes the file. Having a file "open" in LibreOffice doesn't necessarily mean that the file is open in the operating system sense. LibreOffice probably opens it, reads part of it into memory and displays the first page in the editor and then closes it until it needs to read more from it.

Comment: I'd use a less complex "test tool" then LibreOffice.

Comment: Ok, so I got it why it behaves this way when I use text editor tools. Thanks. What about the folder thing? Any idea?

Comment: How do you open the folder? Which tool "opens" the folder?

Comment: Uhm... from the GUI. I didn't try to browse to it using the terminal though.

Comment: GUI folder browsers do all sorts of things. For example: To create thumbnails for image files, they need to read the file.

Comment: I tried to browse to the folder using the terminal. Same thing. It opened and closed the file. I guess I have no choice, but to get used to it, right?

Comment: Strange. I don't get any open event for a regular file when I `cd` to its directory, or even when I do a simple `ls`. If I `cat` the file I get one OPEN and one CLOSE event. I used this example: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html#EXAMPLE